# Is it possible to put divs in this way?

Tags: html, css, z-index

One color on image symbolizes one div. Is it possible to put first div under second, second under third, third under fourth, and fourth under first?

Is it possible to do with pure CSS (without SVG/image etc.)?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Also, read this for ideas on how to achieve this effect: https://css-tricks.com/solving-last-item-problem-circular-distribution-partially-overlapping-items/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also play with transform:rotate

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
}

div p {
  margin: 2em;
}

div :nth-child(1),
div :nth-child(2) {
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0 3em;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

div :nth-child(1) {
  background: black;
  grid-column: 1;
    color: white;
}

div :nth-child(3),
div :nth-child(4) {
 
  background: yellow;
  margin: 2em 1em;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

div :nth-child(4) {
  background: lightgreen;
  grid-row: 2;
}

div :nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateX(1deg)
}

div :nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateX(-1deg)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>one</p>
  <p>two</p>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>four</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope - tis is impossible (at least by using z-index layers) - however you can use some trick to get this effect e.g use 5 div-s:

```css
.boxA {
   position: absolute;
   width: 97px;
   height: 175px;
   background: black;
   left: 17px;
   z-index: 2;
}

.boxB {
   position: absolute;
   width: 248px;
   height: 60px;
   background: yellow;
   top: 32px;
   z-index: 3;
}

.boxC {
   position: absolute;
   width: 248px;
   height: 60px;
   background: #00ff7b;
   top: 112px;
   z-index: 1;
}

.boxD {
   position: absolute;
   width: 62px;
   height: 175px;
   background: cyan;
   left: 157px;
   z-index: 0;
}

.boxE {
   position: absolute;
   width: 62px;
   height: 100px;
   background: cyan;
   left: 157px;
   z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxA"></div>
<div class="boxB"></div>
<div class="boxC"></div>
<div class="boxD"></div>
<div class="boxE"></div>
```